# C# return derived class in abstract class

Tags: c#

I would like to create a NMEA message parser for GPGGA, GPGSV, and etc. Each of the message is derived from the abstract class NMEAMsg.

So I would need to overwrite the `parseToken` for each of the message type:

But, I do not know how to return the derived class in the abstract class?

I am getting `Invalid CastException unhandled by user` when run this code

I need the `public static NMEAMsg parse(string src)` method to return the derived class like `GGA` or `GSA`

```
//NMEAMsg.cs
public abstract class NMEAMsg
{
    public static NMEAMsg parse(string src)
    {
        NMEAMsg nmeaMsg = (NMEAMsg)new object();

        var tokens = src.Split(',');
        tokens[tokens.Length - 1] = tokens[tokens.Length - 1].Split('*')[0];

        nmeaMsg.parseTokens(tokens);

        return nmeaMsg;
    }

    public abstract void parseTokens(string[] tokens);
}


//GGA.cs
public class GGA : NMEAMsg
{
    public double latitude;
    public double longitude;

    public override void parseTokens(string[] tokens)
    {
        Double.TryParse(tokens[1], out this.latitude);
        Double.TryParse(tokens[2], out this.longitude);
    }
}

//GSA.cs
public class GSA : NMEAMsg
{
    public double hdop;

    public override void parseTokens(string[] tokens)
    {
        Double.TryParse(tokens[1], out this.hdop);
    }
}

//main.cs
string src = "$GPGGA,123,323*23";

var data = NMEAMsg.parse(src);

if (data is GGA) {
   //Do stuff here  
} else if (data is GSA) {
   //Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: `NMEAMsg nmeaMsg = (NMEAMsg)new object();` looks a bit odd to me... Why do you create a new object and cast your class to it? why not just create your class:  `NMEAMsg nmeaMsg = new NMEAMsg();` ?

Comment: Related to Roman's comment, can you explain what `NMEAMsg nmeaMsg = (NMEAMsg)new object();` does exactly, or what you hope it's going to do?  Is that the line that is giving you the error?  That line makes no sense to me.

Comment: Change `NMEAMsg nmeaMsg = new NMEAMsg();` to `NMEAMsg nmeaMsg = new GGA();`

Comment: @Roman I cant create that class `new NMEAMsg()` because it is an abstract class

Comment: @Rob yes, you could do that but I will have other class derived from NMEAMsg besides the GGA, (example: GSV, GLA, and etc). i need that object creation dynamic based on the type of NMEA msg

Comment: @Tim Then add your logic to decide which class to instantiate. `NMEAMsg nmeaMsg; if (something) { nmeaMsg = new GGA(); } else if (somethingelse) { nmeaMsg = new GSV(); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably need something like this:

```
public static NMEAMsg parse(string src)
{
    var tokens = src.Split(',');
    tokens[tokens.Length - 1] = tokens[tokens.Length - 1].Split('*')[0];

    NMEAMsg nmeaMsg = null;
    if (tokens[0] == "$GPGGA")
    {
        nmeaMsg = new GGA();
    }
    else if (tokens[0] == "$GPGSA")
    {
        nmeaMsg = new GSA();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Unrecognized type: " + tokens[0]);
    }

    nmeaMsg.parseTokens(tokens);

    return nmeaMsg;
}
```

Where you instantiate the correct class based on the beginning of the parsed string, and then call the specific class' `parseTokens()` method implementation to complete the parsing.

Comment: nice solution, just few questions: i) so there is no way for dynamic creating of the derived object? ii) is my API design good or there is other better implementation?

Comment: @Tim What do you mean by `dynamic`? You could do it via reflection, but that's probably a bit overkill for your use case (unless you're going to have 10+ classes). The only other improvement would be to extract the creation into a method, so you do something like `NMEAMsg nmeaMsg = GetParser(tokens[0]);`

Comment: @Rob cuz i will be having about 6 more classes derived from the `NMEAMsg`, if i use the `if else` way, it will be a big, just try other better way to do it, i will check the `reflection` style. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Rob pretty much explained it.  Things can be coded dynamically, but it will never just work magically because we want it to.  Even if you do reflection, you will probably still need to define some mapping/config somewhere that maps the values from your string to class names that you can use to dynamically create instances of using reflection.  I hope you find what you are looking for.